# Mysql Insert with the Select

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named `employees` and `testdept`.In `employees` table there are two fields as `employee_id` and `department`.`testdept` table contains two fields as `epfno` and `deptid`.

Now what I want to do is insert those id's from `testdept` table to `employees` table `department` field where `employee_id` matches with the epfno.

I have tried with the below code. It inserts the data as a new row. That is the problem.

```
INSERT INTO employees (department)
SELECT t.deptid
FROM  testdept t, employees e
WHERE  t.epfno = e.employee_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want an `UPDATE` statement and not an `INSERT` :

```
UPDATE employees e
JOIN testdept t
 ON(e.employee_id = t.epfno)
SET e.department = t.deptid
```

This will update the records in `employee` table with the data from the corresponding row in `testdept` table